# Array push and merge in php

Tags: php, laravel

How to merge one array with multple elements but the same index into on array with all index in PHP.
I have one array look like this and i want to merge into one array.

```
data": [
        [
            {
                "req_recid": "REQ_0000000001",
                "req_name": "user doer",
                "req_branch": "user",
                "req_position": "userdoer",
                "req_from": "ho",
                "req_tpye": "1",
                "req_date": "Sat, Dec 12, 2020 7:36 PM"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "req_recid": "REQ_0000000004",
                "req_name": "Test",
                "req_branch": "Test",
                "req_position": "Test",
                "req_from": "ho",
                "req_tpye": "4",
                "req_date": "Sun, Dec 13, 2020 12:47 PM"
            }
            

        ]
    ]
```

and my expected result i want like this

```
data": [
        [
            {
                "req_recid": "REQ_0000000001",
                "req_name": "user doer",
                "req_branch": "user",
                "req_position": "userdoer",
                "req_from": "ho",
                "req_tpye": "1",
                "req_date": "Sat, Dec 12, 2020 7:36 PM"
            },
            {
                "req_recid": "REQ_0000000004",
                "req_name": "Test",
                "req_branch": "Test",
                "req_position": "Test",
                "req_from": "ho",
                "req_tpye": "4",
                "req_date": "Sun, Dec 13, 2020 12:47 PM"
            }
            
        ]
    ]
```

Anyone can help in PHP please.

Comment: since you mentioned `laravel` tag you may use laravel's `flatten()` collection method in such cases. FYI: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to change a multi-dimensional array to single dimension. `Laravel` has a beautiful collection method as `flatten()`. This flattens your multi dimensional array to single array. In your case you can use:

```
$result = collect($data)->flatten();
```

to get the desired result.

Know more about it: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatten